# Specific WMTS layer not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wmts

I have been able to open WMS/WMTS layers normally until I found this one:

https://mapire.eu/en/map/thirdsurvey75000/wmts/

I don't understand why but it seems to be connected and when I add it to my map the title is shown at the side bar but the map won't load. I tried zooming in and out because some maps show up then. But with this one it just stays blank.

Comment: Looking at the publishers site. it suggests you need a subscription to access the WMTS (despite the fact the link can just be picked up). It might be wise to contact them and see what is required? https://mapire.eu/en/wmts/

Comment: Thank you. I considered that that might be the problem and sent an email to the company in the meantime. I hope they respond! Thank you very much for your response and help :)